# RecyclerView swapAdapter method continues to use the old adapter

Tags: android

When I have new data to insert into my RecyclerView, I do the following:

```
if(mRecyclerView.getAdapter() != null)
    mRecyclerView.swapAdapter(newAdapter, false);
else
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(newAdapter);
```

When `swapAdapter` is called, as I scroll through the list, the old adapter's `onBindViewHolder` method is still being called. The adapters are the same class, just the new one has more items than the old one. So when I scroll to items that only exist in the new adapter, an out of bounds exception is called on the OLD adapter, because that is being called too. Very frustrating. Is `swapAdatper` meant to work a different way than documented or something? Typical.

Comment: could you post the code for your new adapter as well as the stacktrace please. I could imagine a scenario where the stacktrace could may be misleading because the old and new adapter are the same class.